# How do I create a list of files stored in my Amazon S3 bucket and display them as download links?

Tags: python, html, web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I have a number of videos in an Amazon S3 bucket and I want to display them as a list on my website. Clicking on any item in the list will download the video.

I am using Python and Flask. I currently have the urls and names displaying on screen but I cannot download them. In python it would be simple to just use the "get_file" function on the S3 key but I can't figure out how I would call this method. It seems like it should be simple to do but I may have to use javascript in html 'onClick.'

I am new to javascript so that may be an option but I would most of all like to just access the built in boto method.

Currently I have keys:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

def get_video_keys():
key = local_settings.local_vars['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
skey = local_settings.local_vars['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
bucket = local_settings.local_vars['VIDEO_BUCKET_NAME']

conn = S3Connection(key, skey)
mybucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket)
keys = mybucket.get_all_keys()
return keys
```

And also some html to display them using Jinja2 templating.

```
{% for key in keys %}
        <li><div><a href="{{ key.generate_url(3600) }}"> {{ key.name }}</a></div></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Looking on line has only found ways to download all files rather than downloading in response to a click event.

UPDATE 9/5/13

This actually works fine on Firefox but is not doing anything in Chrome/Chromium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [generate_url](http://boto.s3.amazonaws.com/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.generate_url) to generate a url for downloading.

For example:

```
urls = [key.generate_url(100) for key in keys]
```

Then you get some urls which will expire in 100 seconds.

### EDIT

While you have some special character, use urllib.quote to escape them:

```
new_urls = [urllib.quote(url) for url in urls]
```

Comment: Thanks, so I have the url, I have set it as the href value but when I click on it, nothing happens. I hover over it and the link looks fine but it simply doesn't download. (Sorry I'm new at all this)

Comment: I just updated my question with my html. I gave it 3600, double checked my S3 bucket was public and I am really at a loss.

Comment: What actually happens when you click on one of the links you have created?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. I have just noticed that my file name has a space character in it though. S3 didn't complain when I uploaded it but could that be a problem? It doesn't seem to have been converted to '%20' in the URL.

Comment: New development, it only fails in Chrome

Comment: Seems you need to escape those special character.

Comment: Thanks waitingkuo. I'll accept this answer since it works for me on FireFox. While Chrome is still a mystery, I can work with this for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [s3fs](https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/) on your server to "mount" your S3 bucket as a file system. s3fs is an implementation of [Fuse](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) for amazon-S3

Comment: I am looking to deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk so I'm not sure that would work in my case.